# 2 table MYSQL PHP query and application with PHP to populate a HTML grid display

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, grid

Hello and thank you for viewing my question, I'll get into it.

I'm looking to pull a bunch of data stored in two different tables within a MySQL database, assign values from each row into arrays (if this is the best approach), then use this data to populate html grid elements (so that each row is used to populate one box in the grid).

**This will end up as a grid preview for threads within a php-mysql webapp, a user will have threads displayed as 'preview items', which they may click to open the thread in full.
So far this is how I'm approaching the task, do you have any tips or recommendations on how you would do the same?**

idea_thread contains information about the threads, and thumb contains the images used for thumbnails and grid box side.

```
    $result = $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT i.idea_id, i.user_id, i.time, i.title, i.Brief, t.location, t.width, t.height, t.colour 
FROM idea_thread i, thumb t
    WHERE t.idea_id = i.idea_id 
        ORDER BY i.idea_id DESC LIMIT 150,5");  
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $id = $row[0];
        $user = $row[1];
        $date = $row[2];
        $title = $row[3];
        $briefdescrip = $row[4];
        $photolocation = $row[5];
        $width = $row[6];
        $height = $row[7];
        $color = $row[8];
};
```

?>

Thank you for reading and for any tips you may offer.

For somereason this code however returns nothing but a white screen? Any thoughts as to why?

Edits applied as a result of suggestions, reflected in my code **

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
 $mysqli = 'do connect';

   $stmt =  $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT * i.idea_id, 
             i.user_id, 
             i.time, 
             i.title, 
             i.Brief, 
             t.location, 
             t.width, 
             t.height, 
             t.colour 
    FROM idea_thread i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN thumb t ON t.idea_id = i.idea_id 
    ORDER BY i.idea_id DESC"); 

   $stmt->execute();


     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
         //do staff here
     }
```

reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
 and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using both mysql (mysql_fetch_array) and mysqli and are you sure you want an outer join?  A simple way to join is just specifying multiple tables with an identifier like you have (i and t) and then specifying where they are joined like so:

`SELECT i.idea_id, i.user_id, i.time, i.title, i.Brief, t.location, t.width, t.height, t.colour FROM idea_thread i, thumb t WHERE t.idea_id = i.idea_id  ORDER BY i.idea_id DESC`

A left outer join will include all threads even without a correlated id in thumb which may be what you are after:

`SELECT i.idea_id, i.user_id, i.time, i.title, i.Brief, t.location, t.width, t.height, t.colour FROM idea_thread i LEFT OUTER JOIN thumb t ON t.idea_id = i.idea_id ORDER BY i.idea_id DESC`

Since you aren't providing any values, you don't need to use prepare and can just use query with mysqli.

Update: Noticed you had * in the SELECT as well.  This will select all the columns then the ones you specified throwing off your query even more.

So for mysqli, you will want:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query(...);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {

 ... logic here ...

}
```

I used MYSQLI_NUM in fetch_array since you are referencing the columns by number, you can also use MYSQLI_ASSOC: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thank you sir, I shall make changes accordingly! I had just whipped this up as a quick proof before I dedicated a bunch of time to it - so that I may get suggestions exactly like these.

Comment: An update: you don't want * in the SELECT if you are specifying your columns.

Comment: Thanks mate, that * wasn't intentionally left there so well spotted!

Comment: I also added the fetch_array for mysqli, I hope that helps you get to where you need to be.

Comment: After looking more into your script, an left outer may be better for your use.  I take it you may wish to get threads even if they do not have an correlated thumb (thumbnail)?  At least you know of a new way to do a join though.

Comment: Thanks again! I've applied your tweaks and will begin trial and error testing until I get this to work - cheers for the link, I'll read into it now.

Comment: Well I was initially planning on being able to pull these without a thumbnail - though I think I might implement your method and then code my webapp to set a default image / colour / width / height if none are supplied. I think this would reflect a better quality of grid :3 -- Also I tried to upvote your post but sadly I need 15 reputation.